# Remove a components host property in Angular dynamically?

Tags: angular

I have a component that has the following host property:

```
@Component({
  host: {
        '(@routeHomeAnimation.done)': 'animationComplete($event)',
    }
})
```

I only need to use the animationComplete($event) once and would like to remove the host property (@routeHomeAnimation.done) after I use the method.

How can I remove the component's host property?

Comment: `animationComplete(event) { if(!this.first) return; ...`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I want to be able to stop listening to the event in order to save memory.

Comment: Host properties are compiled to component factory. Once it compiled then will never be changed

Comment: Ok thanks for the info : )